# PHP not working on apache2 server

Tags: php, apache

I have an apache2 server running with all these installed:
`apache2 php5 php5-gd php-xml-parser php5-intl php5-sqlite php5-mysql smbclient curl libcurl3 php5-curl`

I have created a file test.php:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

On the server, when opened the web page all that appears is the actual php code, when it should look like this:

[image]

What is the problem I have looked at the apache logs but nothing looks odd.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your server turned on? Is the file saved with `*.php` and in the server dir? Also do you call the file over the server?

Comment: This could be just about anything and without insight in your logs and config it is just a guessing game. By the time you have found the right piece of information to share with us, you will probably have found the issue yourself.

Comment: Have you restarted apache2 after installing php?

Comment: @GolezTrol I know I have been trolling through google for a long time looking for answers but nobody has it! So as a last resort I posted in on here!! I also think it is quite a common error so we need an answer for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using apache, you need libapache2-mod-php5 to make PHP available to the webserver.

On a debian/ubuntu system, it's generally easiest to use tasksel and select LAMP from there.

Comment: Ha I just found that out myself at exactly the same time!

Answer (score 0):

When I have had that problem starting fresh, this has been what I forgot. Create the file `.htaccess` in the website root (same as phpinfo.php) with the following contents.

```
#allows these file types to be read and displayed
AddType application/x-httpd-php php php4 php3 html htm
```

Comment: I have put that into my (empty) `.htaccess` and restarted apache but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) Stacks are pretty simple to setup. Can you maybe link the tutorial you used, so we can see if there are any steps missing?

I would normally use one of these to setup a stack:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/lamp-linux-apache-mysql-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/ is rock solid, with loads of theory.

Things that will help us help you:

- What OS?
- What Distro?

This normally happens to me if I missed a step in installation.